# Migrating a Webpart from Sharepoint 2010 to 2013

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part

I had a webpart that was working on a SharePoint 2010.
Recently I've Published the same webpart using Visual Studio 2012 to my SharePoint 2013 and it gives me this error:

> Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute
>   method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has
>   occurred.

I investigated the correlation ID and found these:

```
Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has occurred. - userCodeWrapperType = "Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWebPartWrapper", userAssemblyGroupId = "BF96A8E23E5B47C389CC5CF342C43ADA-VOy0+2tyhdunHIqGIbaspR0UrhEWEmt8wY1N2UdzPog=", siteCollectionId = "6e1c633b-1513-44bb-9c18-1a2c919f2edb" - Inner Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeSolutionProxiedException: Nullable object must have a value.
Nullable object must have a value. - Request executing userSolution Id "bf96a8e2-3e5b-47c3-89cc-5cf342c43ada" for site collection id " 6e1c633b-1513-44bb-9c18-1a2c919f2edb" has encountered an unhandled exception while executing user code.  
UserCodeExecutionProxy call failed with solution code itself. ServiceUrl: tcp://XXXX:32846/SPUCExecutionHost; Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeSolutionExecutionFailedException: Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has occurred. ---> Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeSolutionProxiedException: Nullable object must have a value.       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    Server stack trace:      at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeApplicationHostAppDomainRef.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup, Guid siteCollectionId, Byte[] binaryUserCodeToken, Byte[] proxyOperationToken, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext, Boolea...
ExecuteRequestInSandBox call failed. Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeSolutionExecutionFailedException: Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has occurred. ---> Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeSolutionProxiedException: Nullable object must have a value.       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    Server stack trace:      at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeApplicationHostAppDomainRef.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup, Guid siteCollectionId, Byte[] binaryUserCodeToken, Byte[] proxyOperationToken, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext, Boolean shouldUsageLog, Int32 currentProcessId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCod...
Getting Error Message for Exception Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeSolutionExecutionFailedException: Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has occurred. ---> Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeSolutionProxiedException: Nullable object must have a value.       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    Server stack trace:      at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeApplicationHostAppDomainRef.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup, Guid siteCollectionId, Byte[] binaryUserCodeToken, Byte[] proxyOperationToken, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext, Boolean shouldUsageLog, Int32 currentProcessId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode...
```

What gives?

Comment: is this sandbox solution in 2010?

Comment: yes, it's a sandbox solution

Comment: their is no easy way, check this post and follow the links in it. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/37792432-6cd7-4e74-bbe9-46098b19e1f8/deploy-sharepoint-2010-sandbox-solution-to-sharepoint-2013